# jQuery mouseover on page load

Tags: jquery

I have created a drop down menu using jQuery's mouseover event.
I would like to stop the event triggering if the cursor is over the menu on page load.

What I have seen happening is, the user clicks on a menu item which causes the relevant page to load. If they don't move their cursor, when the next page has loaded the mouseover event automatically fires becuase they are still hovering over the menu!

When this happens, the user doesn't realise the page has loaded; they just sit there waiting.

If you'd like to see what I mean, go to www.snowrepublic.co.uk and click on say, Gloves but dont move your cursor.
The Gloves page will load then the menu will instantly drop down. It's quite a large menu so you can see where the confusion comes from!

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
// Dropdown delay
  var $over = false;
  $('#header-nav li .nav').removeClass('drop');
  $('#header-nav li').mouseover(function(){
    $over = true;
    setTimeout( function(){ if ($over == true) $('#header-nav li .nav').addClass('drop'); }, 200 );
  });

  $('#header-nav li').mouseout(function(){
    $over = false;
    setTimeout( function(){ if ($over == false) $('#header-nav li .nav').removeClass('drop'); }, 200 );
  });
});
</script>
```

Any way to stop the mouseover event firing on page load?

This is strange...I've just noticed this seems to be an intermittent problem. Sometimes the menu doesn't drop down on page load, other times it does????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are getting the effect.. but there is one way to make sure it never happens..

Just bound your code on the first mousemove that occurs in the page ..

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(document).one('mousemove', function() {  
      // YOUR CODE HERE...
    });
});
```

This will only fire once, on the first mousemove, and bind the events then.. so nothing can happen before the user moves his mouse ...

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/4ALmC/embedded/result/

reference : [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one)

> The  `.one()` method is identical to  `.on()`, except that the handler
>   is unbound after its first invocation.

---

**Update**

Ok, this looks like a IE/FF 5+ bug (*or maybe jQuery bug*)..

A workaround for now would be to wrap all this in a timeout to avoid the initial mess in those browsers..

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(document).one('mousemove', function() {  

            // YOUR CODE HERE...

        });
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: I think I need to somehow bind the event so nothing happens before the user moves his mouse by 7 pixels rather than just testing for the user moving his mouse because I have tested hoverIntent and that seemed to cure the problem, and I know hoverIntent doesn't fire until the mouse has moved by 7 pixels. Unfortunately I didn't like the flickering on and off when moving from one menu item to the other with hoverIntent :(

Comment: I've tested in a few more browsers and all seems ok in Opera, Safari and Chrome. The bug only seems to appear in Internet Explorer and FireFox

Comment: @Damian, just posted an updated workaround, although it smells like buggy behavior from the browsers or jQuery..

Comment: That looks to have sorted it Gaby!

Answer (score 1):

I expect that most people with this problem have a dropdown menu that is similar to this. When you hover over the `Your account` or arrow next to it then the menu appears. The problem described would only occur if you click on the `Your Account` text at the top which would go to the page.

[image]

For me the solution was to just prevent the dropdown appearing when hovering over the 'Your Account' text (`.menu-desc`). I was able to do this just by checking the URL to see if you were already on the 'Your Account' page. I don't love this solution but it was simpler than some others described.

```
$('.account-options .menu-desc').on('mouseenter', () =>
{
    if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('youraccount') == -1)
    {
        // show menu and start timer to hide it
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yes and no. Whats happening is what they hover on it and it triggers. In your case the page loads fast and it triggers without the user noticing the change. In my case I saw it disappear for a split second. so hears what you can do.

1. have the page go to top on load

   $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
2. add an animation so it is more obvious a new page has loaded and they are hovering over link.
3. use hoverintent plugin (doesn't trigger onmouseover for n milliseconds)
4. change the design

Comment: or what the Gaby said. I did not think of that

Comment: Thanks, I have tried using hoverIntent but didn't like the effect when moving from one menu item to another; the menu disappears and reappears on each mouseout/mouseover

Comment: another complex way that I can suggest (never tried but a thought) is to put it all in a function and run it if a: the page loads and they are not having over it or b: they are on it during page load to dont run the function until the leave the area. it would be a lot of code I personally would suggest to move the screen to top.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, but the other way around: I wanted an event to fire on page load if the cursor is over a specific element.

At first I was using 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave', which didn't work, but 'mouseover' and 'mouseout' worked like I wanted them to.

So for you 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' should work without having to bind another event to trigger the binding you actually want (bah, ugly!).